# How to incorporate php code in a request to a web server to protect it's intellectual property

Tags: php, android, mysql

This may be flagged as to broad or open ended, but I was wondering...

I have an android app that I would like to market.  It is a direct api/communicator with a lamp server.  An apk allows for my code to be proprietary and prevent IP theft from what I know, however half of the code is in the php/mysql code of the app.

I can easily just incorporate the mysql procedures into the php script, but is there some way to incorporate the php scripts into the apk thereby at least somewhat protecting the php code which is part and parcel of the intellectual property?

Comment: Side note: apk does not prevent anyone from getting your servers's IP by sniffing. Further: dont incorporate any intellectual property into apk as far as it posible. Keep your php code at the server, it is easier to keep safe, then the apk file.

Comment: Can you not just do a equivalent of a CURL call from the app?

Comment: The server would be a client run server, ie not mine.  And ip to me is any code I have created.  Ie the android app.  I highly doubt I could get a curl command to execute mysqli commands